# Allow a role to assign user roles but not to manage user permissions

Tags: users

on Drupal 7 how I can give to the "special" role the possibility to manage roles of other users (add a role to a user, remove, add more than a role, etc.), but not the possibility to manage all user permissions?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [role delegation module](https://drupal.org/project/role_delegation)

> This module allows site administrators to grant some roles the
>   authority to assign selected roles to users, without them needing the
>   administer permissions permission.
>
> For each role, Role Delegation provides a new assign ROLE role
>   permission to allow the assignment of that role.

Comment: thank you for your response. role delegation work fine but I need to investigate why more than the 'really' user roles are assigned to a user in the form after module activation